# Deploying docker container to heroku produces: nginx error related to privilidges

Tags: docker, nginx, heroku

As the title says, the error I am getting after deploying my app to Heroku and observing the logs:

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
#build stage
FROM node:14-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/ssat-prep/client
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production && yarn build 

#run and serve stage
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/ssat-prep/client/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My nginx.conf:

```
server {

  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

Please help me to deploy this app

Answer (score 2):

Heroku supplies a port for this in the environment variable PORT, and expose in the Dockerfile does not work.

```
#build stage
FROM node:14-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/ssat-prep/client
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production && yarn build 

#run and serve stage
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/ssat-prep/client/build /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

```
server {

  listen $PORT;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```